# How to change device model in build.prop?

Tags: root-access, file-system, customization, google-assistant

The following is my build.prop file. I just can't find the device model option so I can modify it. I'm trying to change my device model to Pixel XL so I can run Google Assistant properly.

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=NMF26V
ro.build.display.id=lineage_titan-userdebug 7.1.1 NMF26V 399d12a5d9
ro.build.version.incremental=399d12a5d9
ro.build.version.sdk=25
ro.build.version.preview_sdk=0
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.all_codenames=REL
ro.build.version.release=7.1.1
ro.build.version.security_patch=2017-01-05
ro.build.version.base_os=
ro.build.date=Tue Jan 31 23:31:20 PST 2017
ro.build.date.utc=1485934280
ro.build.type=userdebug
ro.build.user=jenkins
ro.build.host=phenom.zifnab.net
ro.build.tags=release-keys
ro.build.flavor=lineage_titan-userdebug
ro.product.brand=motorola
ro.product.name=lineage_titan
ro.product.board=MSM8226
# ro.product.cpu.abi and ro.product.cpu.abi2 are obsolete,
# use ro.product.cpu.abilist instead.
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist=armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=
ro.product.manufacturer=motorola
ro.product.locale=en-US
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.board.platform=msm8226
ro.build.characteristics=default
ro.cm.device=Pixel XL
# end build
```

Update: I have further changed the manufacturer and brand to Google and the product to Pixel XL, but it still had no effect.

Comment: It was a pain putting your long block of `build.prop` into proper blockquote... I removed some irrelevant parts.

Comment: @Andy Appreciate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it manually, here's an app that does it for you: [Get Assistant - Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trivisionzero.getassistant). From app comments in Play and local markets, it's verified to work with multiple models even on LineageOS.

Comment: That app is not compatible for my device..I tried to use other build.prop editing tools..

Comment: @VickyShankar Says that on Play Store? Download it elsewhere e.g. APKPure.

Comment: It worked for me, I replaced every "motorola" reference in the build.prop to "google"(strictly lowercase) and changed device to Pixel XL..also make sure all permissions are given to Google App. Love my new Assistant.
Thanks @Andy you certainly helped.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your branding is set to Motorola. Not going to work. Replace with Google. (if that dose not work, try HTC, Google's contracted manufacturer)